# How to replace values in a table number to word

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Rails Api. In the "attribute" table, the "attribute_type" field uses numbers. I want to replace these numbers with certain words. For this I do the following:

attributes_controller.rb:

```
class AttributesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_attribute, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @attributes = Attribute.all

    render json: @attributes
  end

  def show
    render json: @attribute  
  end

  def create
    @attribute = Attribute.new(attribute_params)

    if @attribute.save
      render json: @attribute, status: :created, location: @attribute
    else
      render json: @attribute.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if @attribute.update(attribute_params)
      render json: @_attribute
    else
      render json: @attribute.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end  
  end

  def destroy
    @attribute.destroy
  end


  private

    def set_attribute
        @attribute = Attribute.find(params[:id])
    end

    def attribute_params
        params.require(:attribute).permit!
    end
end
```

attribute.rb:

```
class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend ActiveHash::Associations::ActiveRecordExtensions
    self.table_name = 'ATTRIBUTS'
    self.primary_key = 'attribut_id'
    belongs_to :attribute_type, foreign_key: 'attribut_type' 
end
```

attribute_type.rb:

```
class AttributeType < ActiveHash::Base
  include ActiveHash::Associations
  has_many :attributes, foreign_key: 'attribut_type'

  self.data = [
      {id: 0, name: 'Text', type: 'text'},
      {id: 1, name: 'Date', type: 'date'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Number', type: 'number'}
  ]
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :attributes do
    collection do
      get 'attribute_type'
    end
  end
end
```

What is not done or what is not enough to replace numbers with words from the "attribute_type" model?

When I try to navigate through this url `/attributes/attribute_type`, this error occurs:

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'attribute_type'
>   could not be found for AttributesController):

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward. It's looking for an attribute_type action in the AttributesController...which does not exist.

Comment: If `attributes_types` is type integer, why not use `enum attributes_types: [:text, :date, :number]`? http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html
--- Take care of the syntax `attribute` <> `attribut`, `attributes` <> `attributs`

Comment: There is not action attribute_type present in the controller as the error clearly says.  what is the functionality you want on hitting this url?

Comment: @Bijendra Output of words from the model for the place of numbers. And if I write in this controller "show", " index" will "AttributeType" work for the model?

Comment: I guess you want to perform some action on the model and display the response in the view. Calling the show action will display the page, but will not perform the action you require. Please make a call to the action in the 'show' method in controller.